# Что означается параметр isBestMatch на Binance?

Tags: binance

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#recent-trades-list

isBuyerMaker я так понял если true то это покупка, а вот что означает isBestMatch?

```
GET /api/v3/trades 

[
  {
    "id": 28457,
    "price": "4.00000100",
    "qty": "12.00000000",
    "quoteQty": "48.000012",
    "time": 1499865549590,
    "isBuyerMaker": true,
    "isBestMatch": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

isBestMatch просто означает, что цена покупателя была согласована с продавцом

Источник: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/374